# CSS Vertical Align Text

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, and have the following:

[image]

As you can see, the text "Ashton marais" is not vertically centered with the image. How can I achieve this with css?

**html**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-avatar (click)="addPhoto()" item-left class="wrapper wrapper-job">
    <img [src]="jobModel.avatar64 ? jobModel.avatar64 : 'images/blank-profile-picture.png'">
    <P *ngIf="!fromSearch && personModelLoggedIn && jobModel.person.id === personModelLoggedIn.id">EDIT</P>
  </ion-avatar>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <h3 class="job-person-name">Ashton Marais</h3>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

**css**

```
.job-person-name {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I added the `job-person-name` class, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Css Flex properties can be used to vertically align a text.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.job-person-name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
  <h3 class="job-person-name">Ashton Marais</h3>
</div>
```

Resulting in:

[image: Flex aligned text]

Here is the code for above image.(http://codepen.io/dpes/pen/gLPjmQ). 
Hope it helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

I can't show you the exact thing but I can give an idea about the structure in the below snippet.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Used for vertical centering child elements */
  justify-content: center; /* Used for horizontal centering child elements */
  padding: 20px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="name">John Doe</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`h3.job-person-name` is the only sibling, that's why it has no effect. The siblings that need to be aligned are `ion-avatar` and `ion-row`.

This will still not yield the desired result, the next step depends on whether or not this is the final output. If it is, you could set `h3`'s line-height to the avatar's height.

Comment: thanks for the reply. When you say, 'set the line height', do you mean the `vertical-align` or `height` attribute?

Comment: Neither, I am talking about the actual `line-height` property.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who posted, but I think your solutions work with raw html, but because the Ionic tags add it's own I couldn't get it to work.

What did work however was:

```
.job-person-name {
  padding-top: 21px;
}
```